# Aplicativo com Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Como faço para utilizar maps no aplicativo? É por meio de certificado gerado no meu pc que então valida na web? Consigo fazer aplicação desse gênero no eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem como fazer isso no Eclipse sim, porém, é muito mais fácil e produtivo fazer no Android Studio.

O Android Studio ta na versão 1.2.2 e está bem estável. Includive o Google já recomenda seu uso em produção. Tenho usado e não me arrependi.

No Android Studio, basta clicar com o botão direito na pasta que representa o projeto e seguir "New" > "Google" > "Google Maps Activity"

Isso criará a Activity com o mapa, o campo de meta-data no `AndroidManifest.xml` e um arquivo `google_maps_api.xml`.

Dentro desde último é onde você colocará sua chave da API do Google Maps obtida no console de desenvolvedor do Google. Inclusive, ao criar o arquivo supracitado, dentro dela haverá, em forma de comentário, um pequeno tutorial de como obter a chave e usar a API.

Comment: Muda muita coisa do Android Studio para o Eclipse que possa atrapalhar um iniciante ?

Comment: @DaniloAlbergardi De jeito nenhum, pelo contrário, ele adiciona uma série de facilidades que não estão no Eclipse. Dá uma testada que tenho certeza que vai gostar.

Comment: Mas muda sim, por exemplo ter que comprar uns 8Gb de memória RAM caso você saia do Eclipse para o AS.

Answer (score 2):

Confira na documentação do Google Maps API do Android:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/